# Dynamics of independent Geometric Brownian Motions under risk-neutral measure Q

Tags: option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure, geometric-brownian

Suppose I have two Geometric Brownian motions and a bank account:
$$dB_t=rB_tdt$$
$$
dS=S(\alpha dt + \sigma dW_t)
$$
$$
dY = Y(\beta dt + \delta dV_t)
$$

Where $dW_t$ and $dV_t$ are independent Wiener processes. Now suppose that I have a martingale measure $Q$ such that $d(S_t/B_t)$ is a martingale. Then we have:
$$dS = S(rdt+\sigma dW_t^Q)$$

Is it possible write the dynamics of $Y_t$ under $Q$?

Suppose also I am interested in pricing $Z_t=S_tY_t$. Would I still use the measure $Q$ to price $Z$ or am I using a separate measure $\tilde{Q}$ such that $d(Z_t/B_t)$ is a martingale?

Thanks!

Comment: Presumably $S$ and $Y$ are tradable assets not paying dividends. In that case, the correct risk-neutral measure $Q$ is the one that makes [each](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk-neutral_measure) discounted price process $S_t/B_t$ and $Y_t/B_t$ a martingale.

Comment: @KurtG. So for $Q$ to be the correct risk-neutral measure, $S_t/B_t$, $Y_t/B_t$ and $Z_t/B_t$ all must be martingales? (and therefore all have drift rate $r$?)

Comment: $S$ and $Y$. What is $Z$ economically ? I have not said anything about it. What do you think that is ? When $S$ and $Y$ have their risk-neutral drift what is the drift of $Z$?